# Custom response for 404s in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc

I am migrating a Web API 2 application over to MVC 6 and I'm struggling to figure out how to return a custom response when status codes like 404 or 405 occur. In Web API, I used an `HttpMessageHandler` for 404 and a `DelegatingHandler` for 405.

I am aware of the concept of middleware, but it seems like the middleware isn't executing late enough in the pipeline to capture the 404. Also, generating responses in middleware is sub-optimal because the `HttpResponse` class only exposes raw HTTP parameters like `ContentLength` and `Body`. I would prefer to simply return an `IActionResult` that contains a custom response model like all my regular endpoints do.

Startup code:

```
applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<NotFoundMiddleware>();
applicationBuilder.UseMvc();
```

Middleware:

```
public class NotFoundMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public NotFoundMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next.EnsureNotNull(nameof(next));
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Response?.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
        {
            // context.Response.StatusCode is 200 because context.Response is set to an instance of DefaultHttpResponse
        }

        return _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Is there a good way of accomplishing what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange how you are executing your logic

```
public class NotFoundMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public NotFoundMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
        _next = next.EnsureNotNull(nameof(next));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
        //let the context go through the pipeline
        await _next.Invoke(context);

        if (context.Response?.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound) {
           //execute your logic on the way out of the pipeline.
        }

    }
}
```

and also make sure that you register it early in the pipeline

Comment: I'll try this, thanks. I modified my question to include an additional question about MVC 6's non-use of 405s.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, of course. I'll move the question about 405s to a new question. Do you have any advice regarding an easier way of setting the response content within middleware? Do I really have to serialize everything myself?

Comment: From my understanding You should be able to use it just like you did before. the middleware allows more extensiblity but the process from before hasn't changed that much. a few new interfaces but the structure is more or less the same for example look at this article about routing http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing

Comment: Take a look at this documentation as well https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html#middleware

Comment: I would also suggest taking a look at filters https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html

Comment: Here's a link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856774/how-can-i-have-mvc-6-return-405-method-not-allowed-instead-of-404-not-found

Comment: Thanks, all. I'm very familiar with the documentation. It was simply a stupid bug. That's what I get for listening to StarCraft II Twitch streams at the same time as I work!