# How can I have MVC 6 return 405 Method Not Allowed instead of 404 Not Found?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

It appears that MVC 6 does not return `405 Method Not Allowed` responses when a route matches except for the verb. This is, in my opinion, a regression from Web API 2 because it's not as RESTful. Is there an easy way to change this behavior?

Comment: Is this true of WebAPI controllers as well as standard MVC controllers? Maybe that behavior is specific to MVC?

Comment: In Web API 2, I could rely on the framework returning `405 Method Not Allowed` in the scenario I outlined. MVC 6 appears to return `404 Not Found`.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't care: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with MVC 6's current implementation. A sad oversight, and one that, along with other abstraction failures on Microsoft's part, drove my team and I to use [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org).

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/388